# Updating my table with save () with Eloquent/Laravel 5.3 is updating all rows instead of one

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to update one row using `eloquent Model/Laravel 5.3`. Instead of updating one row, it is updating the column I want to update but in every row in the table.

I am sure I am just missing something but I can't just look at it anymore. Any help would be appreciated...

```
$userUpdate = userTable::placeid($placeId)->userid($userId)->regid($regId)-key($key)->first();
```

That gets me one row as a result.

then...

```
$userUpdate->VALUE = $value;
$userUpdate->save();
```

These three lines update the VALUE column in the table but every single row and not just the one I pulled.

Comment: Can you `dd($userUpdate)` and post in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`update()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#updates) as:

```
userTable::placeid($placeId)->userid($userId)->regid($regId)->key($key)->update(['VALUE' => $value]);
```

Also, make sure that your `VALUE` column is `fillable` is your `userTable` model.